# $T(n) = T(\sqrt{n}) + \sqrt{n}$ solving recurrence

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, computational-complexity

$T(n) = T(\sqrt{n}) + \sqrt{n}$

I would like to try solving this recurrence in big-O/$\Theta$/$\Omega$.

My first idea was to take $n = 2^m$ so:
$$T(2^m) = T(2^{m/2}) + 2^{m/2}$$
Which we rewrite as: $$G_2(m) = G_2(m/2) + 2^{m/2}$$
Where the Master Theorem would give us $G_2(m) = \Theta(2^{m/2})$, and so $T(2^m) = \Theta(2^{m/2})$ so $T(n) = \Theta(n^{1/2})$

Does that make sense?  Thank you for insights on how to work through this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following an answer by @marty, I like to suggest a direct substitution
$$T(n) = T(n^{1/2}) + n^{1/2} = T(n^{1/4}) + n^{1/2} + n^{1/4} = \ldots$$
$$ = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\log \log n} n ^{\frac{1}{2^{k}}} \leq n^{1/2} + n^{1/4}\cdot \log\log n\leq2\,n^{1/2}$$

The lower bound is trivial (see $n^{1/2} \leq n^{1/2} + n^{1/4} + \ldots$), hence $\Theta(n^{1/2})$.

Answer (score 1):

I would go up another level.

In
$T(n) = T(\sqrt{n}) + \sqrt{n}
$
let $n = 2^{2^m}$.

This becomes

$\begin{array}\\
T(2^{2^m}) 
&= T(\sqrt{2^{2^m}}) + \sqrt{2^{2^m}}\\
&= T(2^{2^m/2}) + 2^{2^m/2}\\
&= T(2^{2^{m-1}}) + 2^{2^{m-1}}\\
\end{array}
$

Letting
$T(2^{2^m}) 
=U(m)$,
this becomes

$U(m)
=U(m-1)+2^{2^{m-1}}
$.

You can proceed from here,
the only difficulty being
$\sum_{k=1}^m 2^{2^k}
$.

Comment: I don't quite understand how this is an improvement over my attempted solution? Would we get a tighter bound?

Comment: The recursion is simpler.

Comment: the sum should go up to $m-1$. Otherwise you get different complexity! And the sum is not really a difficulty, since $n^{1/2} >> n^{1/4}$.